# Run command on a Azure VM from bash with Azure CLI

Tags: bash, azure, virtual-machine, azure-cli

I trying to set up a bash script that connects to multiple VM instances on Azure. On each of these instances, I want to execute several commands.

The documentation says I can use the following command:

```
az vm run-command invoke -g RG1 -n Server1 --command-id RunShellScript --scripts "memcached -t 1 -p 11211 &"
```

Due to the '&', the command should execute in the background and should not block further bash commands (at least for my understanding).

But the terminal is blocked and exits with an error:

```
 Long-running operation wait canceled.
```

How is this done the right way?

Comment: If the answer is helpful you can accept it. Or for more help please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Run command uses the VM agent to run shell scripts within an Azure Linux VM. It's a task and needs to return a result to finish the task. Or it will continue to run the task until the maximum time and return time out.

> Outbound connectivity from the VM is required to return the results of
>   the script.

For more details about the limitation of the Run command, see [Restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/run-command#restrictions).